# Substiution cipher - Encoding

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a program in java which will replace(encode/decode) characters of a given input (string) with different characters. So far Ive written some code for the encoding part but it doesn't seem to work and I'm unsure why.

This is the encode part of the Key class, consider that the isValidKey works.

```
public Key (int value){
}

public char encode(char c){

if (isValidKey(value) == true){
    int x = (int)c + value;
    c = (char)x;


    return c;
    }else{
    return '.'; 
    }
}
```

This is the encrypt part of the Cryptic class.

```
public static java.lang.String encrypt(java.lang.String s, Key k){
for (int i =0; i<s.length(); i++) {
        char x = s.charAt(i);
        char c = k.encode(x);
           s = s.replace(x,c);

}
return s;   

}
```

This all compiles but when I test it, it simply doesn't do anything at all, to the given input (string).

What I want to achieve is that when the value of they Key is set to for e.g 5 the input of 'a' would change to 'f'.

This is the isValidKey method

```
public static boolean isValidKey(int value){
if (value >= 0 && value <= 25)
return true;    
else
return false;
}
```

The variable decelerations in the Key class

```
public class Key { 
private int value;
private int c;
```

Comment: you don't seem to store `int value` in the constructor, so I'm assuming that `isValidKey(value)` never becomes true. BTW: you do not need to check for `==true`in an if-clause

Answer (score 4):

`String`s in Java are immutable. `String.replace` does **not** alter the original string, but rather returns a new `String` with the characters replaced.

So, instead of:

```
s.replace(x,c);
```

You should have:

```
s = s.replace(x,c);
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a bit of code I'd like to see: the variable declarations in your `Key` class. The comment from Dragondraikk is probably the clue you need. My bet is that you've got a class level  var called `value` of type `int`, right? So you need the following in your `Key` constructor:

```
this.value = value;
```

I suspect your `encode()` method only returns dots at the moment. If that's the case, this should fix it.

Comment: Yh that fixed it, thanks alot!!!! Now I just have to do it so it distinguishes between upper and lower case letters & numbers, make some sort of loop so when it gets to 'z' it goes back to 'a' and of course write the decode part.